# How to reload part of a web page using iframe instead of ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

The reason I don't want to use ajax to do this is because the part I want to refresh is actually a commenting plugin implemented by other. I just put a snippet of script they provided in my html code and it shows a commenting part under my articles. As it's not a live commenting one, I want to add a refresh button next to it to enable users to just refresh the commenting part to get the latest comments without need for reloading the whole page.

Therefore, I think maybe iframe is an option for me. But the problem is I need to specify the src attribute of iframe. I don't know what value I should use because all I have is just a snippet of script. Can someone give me any idea on this?

By the way, the code snippet is as follows:

```
<div id="uyan_frame"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" id="UYScript" src="http://v1.uyan.cc/js/iframe.js?UYUserId=1674366" async=""></script>
```

Comment: could you include the code for the script include that you're pasting in now?  tough to tell how to add it if we don't know how the script works

Comment: we can guess what the snippit says, but it would only be a guess...until you show us.

Comment: @ben336 I have included the code snippet.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I have included the code snippet.

Comment: this methodology looks kind of suspect to me...just sayin

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss that's actually how major commenting systems like Disqus work, through iframes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the snippet above in an html file like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
         <div id="uyan_frame"></div>
         <script type="text/javascript" id="UYScript" src="http://v1.uyan.cc/js/iframe.js?UYUserId=1674366" async=""></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And then use that file as the src of your iFrame, which you can refresh using javascript.

That said, just because you can do something doesn't mean you should do something.   This is a really hacky way of doing what you're trying to do.  A few alternative options:

1. ***Understand what the script you're using is doing, and work with it.***  Judging by the name of the script and div in the snippet, it may be creating an iframe to begin with.  If thats the case, why not just figure out what that iFrame is called using your browsers debug it and refresh it manually, or modify the script to do so?
2. ***Use a live updating framework***- This may not be possible for you, I don't know your constraints, but there are plenty of great commenting frameworks out there that do live updates.  For instance [Disqus](http://disqus.com/) comes to mind.  Other examples are [facebook comments](http://raventools.com/blog/facebook-comments/) or you could embed a reference to an external site like [branch](http://branch.com/)
3. ***Use Ajax*** - I'm a bit unclear on whether this is your script that you're writing, or a 3rd party script.  If it is your script, then use the generally accepted methods for doing this type of work, unless you have a really great reason not too.  You'll get better support from others, you'll gain more generally applicable experience, and for the most part, best practices gain that name for a reason.  People use "ajax" methods for live updating pages because its effective and useful.  Frames have become much less common on the web because they're clunky and make it difficult for different parts of the page to interact.  If you don't have a great reason not to use the common practice, its usually your best bet.

Comment: Thanks so much for providing those valuable information. Could you please name a few other live commenting frameworks for me. Thanks!

Comment: I added 2 more examples.  I would definitely recommend Disqus though.  Its the most widely used software for this type of thing.

Answer (score 3):

Just create a html page with the script you talked inside about and use this file in the iframe src attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this :

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('your_frame_id');
iframe.src = iframe.src;
```

set the iframe src to its value again, this will cause the frame to refresh, and will work with cross domain frames

Comment: Thanks, man. But the problem now is how to create this iframe instead of how to refresh the iframe.

Comment: Create a HTML page, include the script inside it, then use an iframe in your main page showing the new one. But this really looks ugly to me :/